# Como aumentar o tempo de conexão para download?

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Dentro do meu projeto, no `.htaccess`, tenho setado as seguintes configurações, para um sistema de troca de arquivos da empresa:

```
php_value memory_limit 6000M
php_value post_max_size 6000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 6000M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 360000
```

Mas tenho recebido algumas reclamações em downloads de arquivos "grandes" (acima de 120MB) que o download simplesmente para exatamente em 120mb e aparece "Mal Sucedido" no browser. Se a pessoa clica no reiniciar ele continua do ponto que parou, mas mais ou menos no mesmo tamanho para de novo.

Existe alguma configuração adicional que preciso fazer, além destas mostradas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recentemente estive com o mesmo problema do download dos arquivos pararem em 120mb e só resolveu após mudar essas configurações no Apache httpd.conf:

```
AcceptFilter http none 
AcceptFilter https none 
EnableSendfile off 
EnableMMAP off
```

Referência: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=23294

Comment: Bá, só tirei o EnableMMAP e realmente passou dos 120mb. Só ficou um pouco mais lento...

Comment: Neste caso é melhor verificar se o problema está no arquivo, comigo aconteceu com videos, tive que mudar a codificação de todos.